# An element in an array changed unnormally

Tags: c++, codeblocks

CodeBlocks 17.12, win10

The second element of the array "theQueue" shows different before and after the line "cin>>theNumber;" in the main function.

I found the problem by adding "Q.display();" before and after to print the elements of the array "theQueue".

Besides, in the function "bool Queue::enqueue(int number)" the variable "sequence" also changed unnormally.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Queue
{
public:
    Queue(int theSize);
    bool enqueue(int number);
    int dequeue();
    int peek(int number) const;
    int getSize()  const;
    void display()  const;
private:
    int size;
    int theQueue[];
    int sequence;//record the current position
};
int main()
{
    int sizeValue,theNumber;
    cout<<"Enter the queue's size(less than 11): \n";
    cin>>sizeValue;
    Queue Q(sizeValue);
    while (true)
    {
        Q.display();
        cout<<"Please input a number to fill up the queue: \n";
        cin>>theNumber;
        Q.display();
        if (Q.enqueue(theNumber)==false)
            break;
    }
    cout<<"Now the queue have "<<Q.getSize()<<" elements,they are:\n";
    Q.display();
    cout<<"The first element in the queue is: "<<Q.dequeue()<<endl;
    cout<<"Now the queue have "<<Q.getSize()<<" elements,they are:\n";
    Q.display();
    return 0;
}
Queue::Queue(int theSize)
{
    int aQueue[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
         theQueue[i]=aQueue[i];
    size=theSize;
    sequence=0;//the initial position is 0
}
bool Queue::enqueue(int number)
{
    theQueue[sequence]=number;
    sequence=sequence+1;
    if (sequence>=size)
    {
        cout<<"The queue is full!\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
int Queue::dequeue()
{
    int firstNumber;
    firstNumber=theQueue[0];
    for (int i= 1;i<size;i++)
         theQueue[i-1]=theQueue[i];
    size=size-1;
    return firstNumber;
}
int Queue::peek(int number) const
{
    return theQueue[number];
}
int Queue::getSize() const
{
    return size;
}
void Queue::display() const
{
    for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
         cout<<theQueue[j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: That code you show should not even build. Unsized arrays are not allowed. And if your compiler for some reason allow it as an extension, its size will still be zero and all indexing will be out of bounds.

Comment: I'm more curious about why you thought this would work. Btw, the IDE is uninteresting; you would instead post the compiler version and flags used, but we don't need that here as the real problem is so obvious.

Comment: Unsized arrays are used in C, but different way. Anyway there is no reason to use them in C++ (especially it is not legal C++ code)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it compiles with gcc, that's extension that makes some C code correct.

Answer (score 0):

`theQueue` got size 0. Writing to `theQueue[0]` it would have undefined effect, most likely writing into `sequence` field (0th array element and field have same size and address - implementation of gcc). Writiting or reading any other element would result in undefined behaviour, posssibly program crash